# Google Sheets - How to return a value based on a date and a condition

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

Google Sheet - I have a table with sales_targets per sales_staff that are effective until a new date. In the table below, the monthly target for Bob from 2 Mar 2019 was $11,000, which then changed on 6 Apr 2020 to $12,100.

[image]

Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qqRBiEd9TmjBuTAlrukNIodsAjUnEf-cnMMo3VCpoVc/edit?usp=sharing

I need to return a value (Sales_Target) based on two input values (the Date and Sales_Name). It must return the Sales_Target for the Staff_Name **for the period when that target was active**. Once the date is changed, it will need to select the new target for the Sales_Staff based on that selection date/period. Hopefully this table below can explain it better:

[image]

I can do vlookups, but that is where my talent ends. The date condition for a period of time until the next date has got me stumped. I've tried to look online, with INDEX / MATCH, MAXIFS functions, but I haven't come right.

Comment: `Couple of queries` **1.** Tim's first date in the table is 2-mar-2019 ($9000), How is **1-Jan-2019+Tim** pickup up the $9000 value. **2.** Is **16-Aug-2021+Gary** value supposed to be $1210 OR $1331?!

Comment: 1) If it can pick up that any dates before the first date 2-mar-2019, be allocated to 2-mar-2019. However, this shouldn't be a problem as I won't input a date before 2-mar-2019. 2) In the table, the final date change was 15-Aug-2021 so the target will need to be $1331. If the date was 14-Aug-2021, it would return $1210

Comment: Gary's date in E6 (16 Aug 2021) falls in b/w 7-jun-2021 ($1210) and 15-aug-2022 ($1310); so technically shouldnt it pick $1210?!

Comment: Ohh, I see my error, the year was meant to be 2022 (apologies). You are 100% correct, 16-Aug-2021 is $1210, if the date was 16-Aug-2022, then it would be $1310.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(E2:E,F2:F,lambda(e,f,if(or(e="",f=""),,let(Σ,sort(ifna(filter(A:C,B:B=f)),1,1),xlookup(e,index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,3),+index(Σ,,3),-1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: You're a LEGEND, thank you!!!